# render raw HTML in a Symfony controller

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to render a template to a string in a symfony controller and avoid escaping it. 
I don't want to disble twig escaping globally.
Kind of applying the `|raw` filter in the template itself, but from the controller.

I imagine something like

```
$rendered_unescaped = $this->container->get('templating')
        ->render($templatehere, $paramshere, 
           array('autoescape'=>false));
```

By the way, I have wishfully tried the previous with no luck indeed.

This need apears when I want to add an html chunk to an ajax json response and realize that I am getting htmlentities all around.

Thanks,
javier

Comment: are you sure, the string is escaped by `twig` and not by `javascript`

Comment: I think you are right. I have further tested and actually is not been escaped in the symfony side. Think I should just remove the post.

Comment: Leave the post, I was looking at the same after mistakenly used jQuery .text() instead of .html() ...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `autoescape` tag

```
{
    "foo": {
        "html": "{% autoescape false %}<p>Yo, <span>{{ name }}</span>, I'm real happy for you, and Imma let you finish...</p>{% endautoescape %}"
    }
}
```

Also, I haven't tested this, but you could change the default strategy of the Twig templating.

```
$this->container->get('templating')->getExtension('escaper')->setDefaultStrategy(false);
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. In the first option you have to edit the template (so no what I'm after). I've tested the second. Got an error, but fixed if you change 'templating' for 'twig'. Still doesn't work for me... because I'm affraid that I might have misslocated the problem. Now I think is in the js side. sorry :-( . my bad

Comment: @javigzz no problem, I actually learned something looking into this out anyway ;)